# How do I adjust for stock splits in my dataset?

Tags: r, finance

So for my thesis I have a very big dataset of around 4000 stocks called Data.
I now need to adjust for stock splits but I'm not quite sure how to do it.
I have a column for the Closing price of the stock called DlyClose and a column for the factor of the stock split called DlyFacPrc (see picture). I would like to create a column called AdjClose.
[Dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLN1Y.png)

I tried the following:

```
Data$AdjClose <- Data$DlyClose * Data$DlyFacPrc
```

This doesn't work however because the split factor returns to 1 after the split.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.